# Can Self-Hosted Objects be avoided for Facebook "stories"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In order to create Facebook "stories" like "Joe beat Jane in (some game)", it seems you have to create these pseudo-HTML files ("Self-Hosted Objects") that you have to host on your own server, that Facebook will fetch data from.

I am just wondering: Is it absolutely necessary to create these files, or is there some way to avoid them?

It seems to me that all the metadata that is going to be displayed, like username, photo, etc. is already on Facebook, so why is it necessary specify this explicitly in an external file?

Comment: Weird! I just asked the ["same" thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010988/facebook-open-graph-and-objects-metadata) in a similar way just some minutes ago.. Waiting for some responses in order to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using self-hosted objects, you can look into using the Object API, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/

Specifically go to the section on app-owned objects. So instead of creating the files with the metadata you can pre-create object instances. There are two ways to create the objects:

1/ Using the object browser: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser

2/ Through an API call, essentially you POST to the https://graph.facebook.com/app/objects/ end point, where  represents your Open Graph object type, ex: myappnamespace:meal for say a meal object.

In the specific example you're asking for, where the object could be someone, ex: a Facebook person, you could even use the Facebook's vanity URL of an object to represents a "profile" object. For a related example, see the Friend Smash game sample https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/games/open-graph/#step3

Comment: About the procedure described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/share-using-object-api/#step1) do I need a concrete domain, a site on which publish the object or can I use fictitious domain or one derived by Facebook and my app namespace?

Comment: I would recommend using a domain you own, just in case down the line you need to actually make the links work from the web, you would then want to own the domain. Theoretically though, if you're building only a native app then you coud use a ficticious domain as you'll be passed this link when your app is called from someone clicking the link and you can process it however you wish to.

Comment: @CAbernathy Can I use self hosted object for custom story sharing in android ? If yes, then if you can provide any valuable link it will be great help for me. Please check my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995978/how-to-use-self-hosted-objects-to-create-custom-stories-in-android).